# WCF Service Exception Handling

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have developed a WCF service which is used to communicate with the Database. I consumed this service from my WPF application for accessing the database. In future, we are planning to have a Web Client also. Currently we are hosting the service as windows service in the server.

My question here is, If any exception is thrown in the server means, I want to notify the client about the exception. Also, I don't want the service to be killed. How do I achieve this?

For Ex: If the database went offline, when the service try to access that DB, it throws an exception. I didn't handle those exception using try catch. These type of unhandled exceptions leads my WCF service to close.

Comment: Could you post some code to show how you are currently stopping your service when an Exception is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a FaultContract for your WCF Service methods. When an exception occurs on the server, you can throw a FaultException. The client side can capture this FaultException and handle it.

I hope the link is helpful. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26320/WCF-Error-Handling-and-Fault-Conversion

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to do anything. The server is not killed if an exception occurs. The client will receive the exception.

If you want, you could add error handling with the `IErrorHandler` interface and you should use fault contracts so that the clients know if they get an expected or unexpected error. See here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg281715%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: fejesjoco: I am hosting the service as Windows Service, and the service is stopped if exception occurred.

Comment: Then it is not WCF's fault, but something else. WCF catches exceptions in services, so it cannot be the reason.

Comment: fejesjoco: I handled the exception in the service using Try..Catch and from the catch block I throws FaultException to notify the client. Thanks for your help.